# Прием всех пакетов, приходящих на сокет машины

Tags: c++, qt, сокет

Скажите пожалуйста, каким образом следует организовывать сокет на Qt таким образом, чтобы он ловил все пакеты, приходящие на указанную пару IP:порт?
На C# я делал что-то вроде

```
 BoardListen_1 = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Raw, ProtocolType.IP);  
 BoardListen_1.Bind(new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse("192.168."+Local_Ip.Text), 67));
 BoardListen_1.SetSocketOption(SocketOptionLevel.IP, SocketOptionName.HeaderIncluded,true);

 byte[] byTrue = new byte[4] { 1, 0, 0, 0 };
 byte[] byOut = new byte[4] { 1, 0, 0, 0 }; 
 BoardListen_1.IOControl(IOControlCode.ReceiveAll,  byTrue, byOut);
 BoardListen_1.BeginReceive(byteData, 0, byteData.Length, SocketFlags.None,  new AsyncCallback(OnReceive), null);
```

На Qt можно организовать что-то подобное?

Comment: Т.е. мне по сути нужен raw сокет, а куте предлагает абстрактный, тсп или удп. Может быть существуют ещё какие-то дополнительные модули?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если требуется безотносительно протоколов TCP или UDP, то для открытия такого сокета используйте нативный для операционной системы код. Фреймворк Qt кроссплатформенный, а значит всё платформозависимое упрятано там в приватные классы.

Тем не менее, если имеется дескриптор нативного сокета, то можно использовать непосредственно `QAbstractSocket`. У этого класса имеется метод `setSocketDescriptor()`, который и позволит подключить уже созданный сокет к Qt-приложению.

**UPDATE**

Хотя, возможно стоит попробовать использовать `QAbstractSocket::bind()` напрямую. Метод не чисто виртуальный и, вероятно, откроет сокет на прослушивание в том виде, в котором требуется.

Comment: Вот кстати важный вопрос - на что байндить? На броадкаст или на айпи локальной машины?

Comment: @ТарасКолеско, никто не мешает попробовать оба варианта, если необходимо. Тем более, что устанавливать значение для использования одного из них нужно в любом случае в согласии с клиентом.

Comment: Просто bootstrap все-таки UDP по своей сути, но мне нужна информация которую я получал с raw сокетов, а именно поля с МАК-адресами dst и src. Вот и думаю как их оттуда выдрать при помощи qt. Слышал ещё что можно подключить boost и использовать тамошние средства, но хотелось бы ограничиться одним инструментарием.

Comment: @ТарасКолеско, в Qt такого инструментария вроде бы нет. Qt - он больше на GUI ориентирован и поддержки чего-то, выходящего за рамки стандартных сетевых потребностей в нём нет. По boost ничего не могу сказать.